# Cannot remove faucet from vanity

Tags: plumbing

I cannot deduce how to remove the two faucet handles from the vanity.  The T joint is soldered, and I have no way to pull it up through the hole. *(I can loosen the locking nut, but it will not pass the T joint)*

From the top, the handle is corroded.  I removed the screw, but I am not able to unscrew nor lift the handle off so it can fall through the hole.  The collar unscrews, but will not lift up over the handle.

I tried a hex wrench in the fitting to no avail.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There should be another nut/tightener under the counter top.

Comment: get a handle puller, it has arms that pull up under the handle while a screw in the middle pushes down on the center of the top handle.  That or use an angle grinder to chop up the portion above the sink so it can fall through.

Comment: What's the problem?  You have a bigass flanged nut at the bottom of the counter.  Turn that while you keep the threaded portion steady.  You can stick a screwdriver in the side tee, or maybe even a hex bit in the bottom (unclear based on pics, but it looks like there may be a hex socket there).  Or vice versa—keep the flange still and rotate the threaded part.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep working on those handles. Pry them off with a crowbar if necessary. Pour some vinegar or CLR in there to dissolve the corrosion. I'm guessing you don't plan on reusing the old faucet so you could cut the handles off with a rotary tool and cutoff wheel and then remove the collar

Comment: I bought CLR and will try that after work ...